# Why does the YouTube Playlist Player start at the second video?

Tags: youtube-api

Using YouTube Object Player (is being embedded on WordPress so can't use iFrame). Once embedded, when you press play it starts from the second video in the playlist: the first video is skipped over. No idea why. The code was generated with YouTube's own tool here https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo and I've pasted the code below. Any suggestions on how to fix it?

```
<object width="640" height="360">
   <param name="movie" value="https://www.youtube.com/v/videoseries?listType=playlist&list=PL1C53ED506CD9B801&modestbranding=1&rel=0&theme=light&version=3">  </param>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></param>
<embed src="https://www.youtube.com/v/videoseries?listType=playlist&list=PL1C53ED506CD9B801&modestbranding=1&rel=0&theme=light&version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" width="640" height="360"></embed>
</object>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is just simple..
go to https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo

Load the player with your playlist and to enable playlist to start from first video, you just need to put '0' in Go to (enter playlist index no.) column and hit the 'Go' button.

Works for me!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to insert the following code....  **&index=-1**

Comment: <param name="movie" value="https://www.youtube.com/v/videoseries?listType=user_uploads&list=YOURID&version=3&index=-1">

Answer (score 0):

And one more approach i got, even this one is so easy.

To embed playlist, try using:

https://www.youtube.com/embed/?listType=playlist&list=

instead of

http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=

By doing this, your playlist will play from first video onwards.

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like an addition to a previous answer. Try editing your other answer instead of adding a new one. Makes things less confusing.